# Extract contents between specific tags in a textfile - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file with the following information:

```
ALLOC

apple1
orange1
banana1

ALLOC
apple2
orange2
banana2

ALLOC
apple3
orange3
banana3
```

Based on the help from stackflow community, I am now able to read the whole file.I also found out that to extract contents between a tag, for ex, `ALLOC`, I could write:

```
var filelocation = @"c:\Fruits.txt";
var sectionLines = File.ReadAllLines(filelocation).TakeWhile(l => !l.StartsWith("ALLOC"));
```

But this will give me `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
apple1
orange1
banana1    
apple2
orange2
banana2    
apple3
orange3
```

How do I create 3 separate strings as

```
string1 = apple1 orange1 banana1
string2 = apple2 ornage2 banana2
string3 = apple3 orange3
```

In short, need to extract contents between tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some approach how you can return result which you want:

```
string[] words = { "ALLOC", "apple1", "orange1", "banana1", "ALLOC", "apple2", "orange2", "banana2", "ALLOC" };

var result = string.Join(" ", words)
        .Split(new string[] { "ALLOC" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)            
        .Select(p => p.Trim(' '));
```

First I am making single string of all words. Than I am splitting by "ALLOC",  and selecting trimmed strings.

Result is:

```
string[] result = { "apple1 orange1 banana1", "apple2 orange2 banana2" };
```

**For your case**,

```
var filelocation = @"c:\Fruits.txt";
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filelocation);
var sectionLines = string.Join(" ", allLines)
            .Split(new string[] { "ALLOC" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)            
            .Select(p => p.Trim(' '));
```

Comment: @Aruna Thanks for update, but I think that I edited `StringSplitOptions.None` to `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` solutions little bit before you updated post. I think that is better to remove additional code.

Comment: Kat, It would be better to give exact solution to the OP by correcting his code rather than giving a example. Anyways still you can freely edit this further :-)

Comment: @Aruna I see what you saying. Agree with that. Question initially started from `var filelocation = @"c:\Fruits.txt";`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
string fullstr = File.ReadAllText("c:\\Fruits.txt");
string[] parts = fullstr.Split(new string[] { "ALLOC" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<string> outputstr = new List<string>();
foreach(string p in parts)
{
    outputstr.Add(p.Replace("\r\n", " ").Trim(' '));
}
```

Here we read all text at once using `File.ReadAllText` and then splitted it with `ALLOC` and then in the `outputstr` just added the splitted string by replacing `\r\n` that is new line with a space and trimmed the result.

[image: Here is the screenshot of the result]